# Inject @ngrx store as dependency in a factory provider in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm using a function factory in the app.module of my Angular application to initialise one service. Something like this

```
export function analyticsServiceFactory() {
  return ConfigService.env === "development" ? new AnalyticsDevService() : new AnalyticsService();
}
...
const providers = [
  ...
  { provide: AnalyticsService, useFactory: analyticsServiceFactory }
];
```

This was working fine until now.
Problem comes because now I need to inject the state (@ngrx) as a dependency to one of those services. How would I do that?

I know I can add a dependencies to the factory provider, but how do I add the state? Is that even possible?

Also, my store and my analyticsServiceFactory are defined in different modules, which makes it even more difficult.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can require dependencies in the `"deps"` array of the provider definition, then just accept them as parameters in the factory function:

`{
      provide: FooService,
      useFactory: (store: Store<AppState>, httpClient: HttpClient) => {
        return new FooService(httpClient, store);
      },
      deps: [Store, HttpClient]
    }`